# Compact Hausdorff $0-$dimensional Space as the Limit of Inverse Sequence of Finite Discrete Spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Compact Hausdorff $X$  is $0-$dimensional iff it is the limit of an inverse sequence of finite discrete spaces

The reverse implication is simple. However, I have no idea how to do the forward implication. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false if by sequence you mean one indexed by $\Bbb N$, e.g. In that case the inverse limit of finite discrete spaces is compact $0$-dimensional and *metrisable*, so $X$ must be metrisable (otherwise use $\{0,1\}^{\omega_1}$ as a counterexample).

So assuming $X$ *is* moreover metrisable: consider $X$ as a subspace of $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ and use $X_n = X \cap \{0,1\}^{\le n}$ and the obvious projections as an inverse sequence.

Comment: This is actually Problem 6.2.C.(a) of Engelking's General Topology. So, did Engelking make a mistake here, or have I misunderstood that question?

Comment: @IshanDeo He writes inverse **system**. Same idea (Cantor cube embedding), but use finite subproducts ordered by reverse inclusion of index sets instead. It's an early example in chapter 2 when he shows subspaces of products are limits of inverse systems.

Comment: @IshanDeo Example 2.5.3 shows $\{0,1\}^m$ is written in such a way (finite subproducts are all finite discrete) and Proposition 2.5.6. shows we get all subspaces of it, so all zero-dimensional compact spaces.

Comment: @IshanDeo He’s talking about inverse *systems*, not sequences. Embed $X$ into $\{0,1\}^I$ and consider all non-empty $X \cap \{0,1\}^F$ where $F$ is a finite subset of $I$ (a standard way of seeing a product as the limit of its finite sub products (as an inverse system in the natural way, see the first section on inverse limits in chapter 2.